# Why doesn't Directory.Build.props work when building a solution using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Directory.Build.props file located in the same directory as the .sln file.

```
 <Project>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
  <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\$(MSBuildProjectName).xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

When I build the solution using MSBuild, I am able to generate the XML files properly. However, using a Build -> Rebuild Solution task in Visual Studio doesn't generate the XML file.

Is there a difference in how Visual Studio 2017 builds and uses Directory.Build.props as opposed to MSbuild?

Comment: Did you re-open visual studio? at the moment it is necessary to at least close the solution and re-open it. For the old project system (non-.net core / standard projects), it may even be necessary to do that whenever you change the file.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had added the directory.build.props as a solution item. This somehow prevented Visual Studio from picking it up and using it in the build process. Once I removed it as a solution item, this worked fine.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT : do you have any explanation why this happens?

Comment: This sounds like a bug.

Comment: This wasn't the case for me; cs-NET's answer here helped me however (delete your .vs directory which somehow cached the existence of these files).

Comment: clean of .vs folder also corrected this for me

Answer (score 19):

You also might have to delete your .vs directory (or portion of) as it seems to be cached there as well.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/248037/defaultbuildprops-with-langversion-is-not-used-by.html

Comment: This worked for me, however I will monitor my project for the next build. Else I need to apply the answer from @SamlAm

Comment: This worked for me as well. I had a solution with both old and new style csprojs, and the old ones were not picking up the properties from the `Directory.Build.targets` file, even though the SDK-style csprojs were working fine. Once I closed VS, deleted the `.vs` folder and loaded it again, it started working as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check that your project file contains next row in the beginning of file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Without row **Import** 'magic' doesn't happen. So, you need to insert this row to all your old projects

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to cause attributes defined in Directory.Build.props not to show up in compiled DLLs is `GenerateAssemblyInfo` set to false in .csproj file.

In my case this happened during conversion to SDK format.
In such case following has to be removed from .csproj files:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
```