# Run Roslyn analyzers during live code editing but not during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis

The Roslyn code analyzers work both in live code editing and at build time.

However, they slow down the build quite a bit. Therefore, I'd like to disable them during build time - but still use them during live editing.

Is that possible?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23591

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RunAnalyzersDuringBuild` in the .csproj:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>    
     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework> 
     <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>  
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Update:** Some documentation from the comments [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019)

Comment: For reference, here's the relevant documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the previous answer and link to documentation! I wanted to conditionally run these analyzers in my CI build, and for local editing (intellisense), but not for local builds. I accomplished that with a Directory.Build.props file (and a custom msbuild property `-p:CI=true`):

```
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>true</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(CI)' != true">
   <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(CI)' == true">
   <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022

Note: I did have to remove `default.build.props` from the solution items, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52866963/).